# Is there any way to represent a day and time without a full date?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to make a custom data structure that holds a schedule for a particular class in a 5-course course load in university. It doesn't matter to me what year and date the classes are taking place - I only care about the day of the week and the time that it takes place.

How can I represent this without the DateTime? Or is there a way to do this with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own class that holds the bits of data that are important for you.

The [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enumeration is suitable to hold the day of the week and you can model the hours/minutes with `int` fields.

Something like:

```
public struct ClassSchedule
{
  private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
  private int hours;
  private int minuts;

  public ClassSchedule(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int hours, int minutes)
  {
     // test the incoming data for validity and throw exception if not valid
  }
}
```

You need to ensure that the values passed in valid (say hours can be between `0` and `23`, minutes between `0` and `59` and that the enum value passed in is actually a valid enum value.

I suggest making this an immutable value type.

Comment: @agent154 - Modelling concepts in the domain you are working on is a very powerful technique and is a common way to work with objects.

Comment: I opted to use TimeSpan instead of two integers to represent the start time, as well as another TimeSpan to represent the length of the class. But otherwise everything else was similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime and then only display the information in it that you want. Or you can create your own class/struct and store information in it that you get from DateTime.Now.